# How can I install yuuguu on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu

How can I install yuuguu on Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 1):

From [Yuuguu doesn't install on Ubuntu 10.04](http://getsatisfaction.com/yuuguu/topics/yuuguu_doesnt_install_on_ubuntu_10_04) :

> In Ubuntu 10.04 the Sun JRE has been
>   moved from the multiverse repository
>   to the partners repository (which is
>   not enabled by default).
>
> To install Yuuguu you will need to
>   enable the partners repository using
>   the following steps:
>
> 1. Bring up the "Software Sources" settings
> 2. Select the "Other Software" tab.
> 3. Enable the "partner" source.
> 4. Close the settings.
> 5. Try installing Yuuguu again.
>
> Ubuntu have moved the Sun JRE in an
>   attempt to encourage people to use the
>   open source OpenJDK instead. When we
>   first released Yuuguu for Linux we
>   looked at using OpenJDK but there were
>   font issues that broke the client.
>
> We will look at either switching to
>   OpenJDK or updating the installation
>   instructions after 10.04 has been
>   finalised and shipped.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Yuuguu will now install on Ubuntu.  This can be downloaded via the "Your Account" section of the website or via the "Sign Up" links if you don't have an account.